# Chrome passwords and subdirectories

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I have a site, reachable from one uniq URL (i.e. https://my.domain.com/), and differents applications running on his subdirectories :

- https://my.domain.com/myapp1/
- https://my.domain.com/myapp2/
- https://my.domain.com/myapp3/
- ...

On Google Chrome, if I'm logging on **myapp1** with *myuniquser*/**myapp1password** and save these credentials, when I'm loggin on **myapp2** with *myuniquser*/**myapp2password**, Chrome suggests me updating my previous password (myapp1).

It seems that Chrome can't manage different passwords from one uniq user on one uniq site with differents subdirectories.
All I want is to store my different passwords without updating the previous one.

Would anyone have a trick in order to have the behaviour I expect ?

NB : In comparison, using KeePass and its plugin under Chrome, KeePass handles very well the distinction of the subdirectory.

Comment: Run your app as myapp1.my.domain.com and so on.

Comment: @Seth, that absolutely not my aim.
I don't want subdomains, i do want subdirectories.

Comment: @Seth Unfortunately, that's not a solution either, since Chrome's password manager [also doesn't respect subdomains](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/155020184/passwords-for-subdomains-are-not-treated-as-separate-websites?hl=en), so credentials saved on <app1.example.com> will overwrite those saved on <app2.example.com>.

Comment: @zcoop98 with subdomains, on can register the domain in the PSL (https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/) in which case, if I am not mistaken, Chrome *will* handle different subdomains differently. So while that is not a solution the OP likes, it is feasible.

Comment: Nonetheless, I would argue that a solution for paths is needed, given that large sites such as https://www.editorialmanager.com/ and https://manuscriptcentral.com/ operate isolated customer environments under separate paths, not subdomains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's broken, I'm afraid:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3995107?hl=en&msgid=3998358

The recommendation may be to open a ticket so the engineers see it.  I'd recommend placing the ticket on a competing product in the space, like Brave or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefix the username with the name of the app, so you can see from the password manager's dropdown which username to select. There's three variants to this:

1. Register with usernames that begin with `myapp1`, `myapp2`, ...
2. If usernames have to be valid email addresses, check if your email provider supports suffixes like Gmail does with `username+suffix@gmail.com`; then register with `username+myapp1@gmail.com`, `username+myapp2@gmail.com`, ...
3. Prefix usernames *stored in the password manager* with `myapp1`, `myapp2` ..., removing the prefix before submission of the login form